# Insert DropDown Values to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is my html form and php file i have to insert my budget dropdown values by select into database
i have to select values from budget and selected value can insert in database
and my data is inserting in my database when i click twice on submit button

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" id="register-form" onsubmit=" return add();">
    <div class="label"> Name</div><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br />
    <div class="label">Email</div><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
    <div class="label">Phone Number</div><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" /><br />
    <div class="label">budget</div>
    <select id="budget" name="budget">
        <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">0-100</option> <!-- first option contains value="" -->
        <option value="2">100-200</option> 
        <option value="3">200-300</option> 
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit"  onclick="add()" name="submit" />
    <div id="message"></div>
</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $name=$_POST["name"];
       $email=$_POST["email"];
       $phone=$_POST["phone"];
       $budget=$_POST["budget"];
       $insert_query="insert into form(name,email,phone,budget) values ('$name','$email','$phone','$budget')";
       $con=mysql_query($insert_query);
    }

?>
```

Comment: i want from dropdown values can insert only 1,2,3 are insert i want 0-100, 100-200,200-300 can insert

Comment: one thing is that when i click on submit button once it can not insert data to database but when click again it can insert... when refresh the page it can insert data on twice click

Comment: What does `add()` do? And you're wide open to **SQL Injection**. Please migrate to **mysqli_** functions since mysql_ is **deprecated** or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string` to filter your `$_POST` values.

Comment: post the function `add()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dropdown pass option value in variable so change the option value which you want to insert in database**

```
<select id="budget" name="budget">
            <option value="">select</option>
            <option value="0-100">0-100</option> <!-- first option contains value="" -->
            <option value="100-200">100-200</option> 
            <option value="200-300">200-300</option> 
        </select>
```

Comment: why data is inserting on twice click

Comment: you are calling `add` function two times in form `onsubmit` and submit button `onclick`. so remove `onclick='add()'` from your submit button `<input type="submit"  onclick="add()" name="submit" />`

Comment: onclick is for my ajax function

Comment: you are call it two place in form  or submit button

Comment: onclick=add() is my jquery ajax function for click and onsubmit=return add() is the function i remove same problem persisit

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
<select id="budget" name="budget">
            <option value="">select</option>
            <option value="0-100">0-100</option> <!-- first option contains value="" -->
            <option value="100-200">100-200</option> 
            <option value="200-300">200-300</option> 
        </select>
```

Ensure that your field in the database is `string/varchar`

Re-visit the `add()` as well. That might be the cause for inserting successfully after the second click.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="budget" name="budget">
 <option value="">select</option>
 <option value="0-100">0-100</option> <!-- first option contains value="" -->
 <option value="100-200">100-200</option> 
 <option value="200-300">200-300</option> 
 </select>
```

if u want to select multiple option u use

```
<select id="budget" name="budget" multiple="multiple">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST["budget"];` is taking the value that is in the option, in this case the value for "0-100" is 1. If you want the value to be stored in the database use "0-100" as the value.

As far as the insert problem goes, try using this syntax:

```
$budget=$_POST['budget'];
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( database_budget )
        VALUES ('$budget');";
```

the top value being the value in the database and the bottom value being the post value.

This is assuming that you're connecting to the database correctly. Also use single quotes for post values not double quotes.